# How to pass link to file in Django views

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-static

I am very new to Django and trying display an image on an html page by passing the path to the src from the view.

I have this in the 'task1.html' file

```
<figure><img src={% static '{{ main_figure }}' %}></figure>
    
<p>{{ description }}</p>
```

and this in the 'views.py' file

```
def task1(request):
    return render(
        request,
        "App/Tasks/task1.html",
        {
            'main_figure' : "assets/placeholder_img.png",
            'description' : "Placeholder image and text"
        }
    )
```

But the image does not show. If I remove the `'main_figure' : "assets/placeholder_img.png",` line and change
`<figure><img src={% static '{{ main_figure }}' %}></figure>`

to         `<figure><img src={% static 'assets/placeholder_img.png' %}></figure>`

the image displays, so the issue seems to be with the views function.

I have tried passing different parts of the src from the view, e.g.

`<img src={{ main_figure }}>`

with `'main_figure' : "{% static 'assets/placeholder_img.png' %}",`

and

`<img src={% static 'assets/{{ main_figure }}.png' %}>`

with `'main_figure' : "placeholder_img",`

but it always shows the little image not found icon.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. {{xxx}}   is just printing a variable xxx (so what is inside {{ }}) therefore no spaces are needed.
2. {% xxx %}  is executing a tag and spaces before/after % are necessary
3. if you need to use a variable inside tag no need to use {{  }}: {% static main_figure %}

Comment: It works! Thanks very much, I hadn't realised that {{ }} is to print the variable, not to indicate a variable to be replaced. Thanks again